# OpenLayers caching

Tags: caching, openlayers

I have my own data, and I want to create cache images to be used with OpenLayers, I want the format to be WWJ format and 256x256x size, I don't want to create the images, I just want a program that loops though the layer and request all images from my server.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use mapserver or geoserver? If you do, you can think about this one: **[TileCache](http://tilecache.org/)**. It will automatically  create the tiles, for your layer.

and here is the **[Tutorial of TileCache](http://tilecache.org/docs/README.html)**

Comment: your answer is form valid, but as you ask question to the OP, have you notice its account is deleted? ;)

Comment: OH, yes. thx let me know jbh... I didn't notice that -_-!! Actually this is my first post on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Layer.TileCache` object, documented here:

http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/TileCache-js.html

That is used to retrieve your own prerendered tiles, and you can specify file extension, size and url.